# Python Scikit-image processing of Gel electrophoresis data

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, scikit-image

I never used computer vision stuff before and thought I can use python for analysis of Gel Electrophoresis. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN5IvS96wNk) is a video explaining what is happening if you are not familiar with the process.

So I took a pic from wikipedia of a gel then use a grayscale filter, then a bilateral filter to get rid of smudges and artifacts, and then I used a Otsu filter to separate out the prominent bands.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data, io
from skimage.filter import threshold_otsu, denoise_bilateral
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.measure import regionprops
from skimage.color import label2rgb, rgb2gray


image = io.imread('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Gel_electrophoresis_2.jpg')


#grayscaling
gray_image = rgb2gray(image)

# bilateral filtering
bilat=denoise_bilateral(gray_image, sigma_range=0.05, sigma_spatial=20)

# apply threshold Otsu
thresh = threshold_otsu(bilat)
bw = closing(bilat > thresh, square(1))

#print process
def show_images(images,titles=None):
    """Display a list of images"""
    n_ims = len(images)
    if titles is None: titles = ['(%d)' % i for i in range(1,n_ims + 1)]
    fig = plt.figure()
    n = 1
    for image,title in zip(images,titles):
        a = fig.add_subplot(1,n_ims,n) 
        if image.ndim == 2: 
            plt.gray() 
        plt.imshow(image)
        a.set_title(title)
        n += 1
    fig.set_size_inches(np.array(fig.get_size_inches()) * n_ims)
    plt.show()

#print data
show_images(images=[image, bilat, bw], titles=['Normal', 'Bilateral filter', 'Otsu Threshold'])
```

Here is what the results currently look like
[image: Wikipedia Gel electrophoresis]

I have 4 problems I got stuck on:

1. Using the otsu threshold causes some data loss from light color bands is there better way get the band data?
2. Is there a way to return the results from each row to a numpy/pandas array where the bands are displayed on a matrix? (ie 0 for no bands, 1 for light band, 2 for medium band, 3 for heavy band) This will allow detecting bands that are matching with the DNA Ladder(reference row).
3. What method can be used to calculate the distance from the wells to the bands.
4. If the picture is not taken straight would I need something called [Image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration)? If so where do I find it in `scikit-image`?

Last thing I am using python 3 and the last stable version of scikit-image if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps get in touch with the authors of https://github.com/hugadams/pyparty, which is built on top of scikit-image.

1. You may want to first equalize the image (see the "exposure" submodule)
2. You'll first have to do some kind of peak detection (see the "feature" submodule)
3. I'm not quite sure what you are asking here
4. Rather image warping (see the "transform" submodule)